# Float Right Makes Everything Else Move Left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to finish off a project of mine by adding in a form which will float right of the hotel logo, but when I enter - float:right; - it basically moves the hotel logo to the left also which I don't want. I have tried - position:absolute; - but no luck either! Please find the link attached with all my work, thanks to anyone who answers!

http://www.mediafire.com/download/fwvr66dq7ugy6ld/Files.rar

```css
#body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
#topbotbar {
  border-top-width: 3em;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #21334b;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  border-bottom-width: 3em;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #21334b;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
#logo {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#navtop {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  color: #21334b;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: -10px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #D8D8D8;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #D8D8D8;
}
#navbot {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  color: #D8D8D8;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -40px;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 14px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #D8D8D8;
}
#banners {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.75em;
}
#banners img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
#banners img.active {
  z-index: 3;
}
.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #21334b;
  padding-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 9em;
}
.head {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #a5945d;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #D8D8D8;
  margin-left: 150px;
}
.text {
  color: #21334b;
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
}
#topleft {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
#topleft img {
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
}
#topright {
  float: right;
}
#topright img {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 3em;
  padding-right: 4em;
}
```

```html
<body id="topbotbar">

  <div id="body">

    <div id="topleft">
      <a href="http://www.tripadvisor.ie/Hotel_Review-g186612-d212584-Reviews-Lake_Hotel-Killarney_County_Kerry.html">
        <img src="Images/tripadvisor.png" alt="advertisement" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <form style="float:right;" method="post" enctype="text/plain" action="mailto:Alan.Philpott@students.ittralee.ie" class="text">
      <label>Check-In</label>
      <br>
      <input name="Date" maxlength="7" size="1" placeholder="30 Nov" type="text">
      <input name="Year" maxlength="4" size="1" placeholder="Year" type="text">
    </form>

    <div id="logo">
      <img src="Images/lakehotel.png" alt="Lake Hotel Logo">
    </div>

    <!--Insert Check Available Dates Here-->

    <div id="navtop">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>The Hotel</li>
          <li>Rooms</li>
          <li>Dining</li>
          <li>NewsLetter</li>
          <li style="border-right-width:1px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#D8D8D8;">Gallery</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="banners">
      <img src="Images/page1top.jpg" alt="Hotel View" class="active" />
      <img src="Images/page1top2.jpg" alt="Hotel View" />
      <img src="Images/page1top3.jpg" alt="Hotel View" />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          var active = $('#banners .active');
          var next;

          if (active.next().length > 0) {
            next = active.next();
          } else {
            next = $('#banners img:first');
          }

          next.css('z-index', '2');

          active.fadeOut(1500, function() {
            active.css('z-index', '1').show().removeClass('active');

            next.css('z-index', '3').addClass('active');
          });
        }, 5000);
      });
    </script>

    <p class="title">The Hotel</p>
    <p class="head">A FAMILY RUN HOTEL IN THE HEART OF KILLARNEY</p>
    <img style="float:left;" src="Images/offersonline.png" alt="Offers">
    <p class="text">Nestling on the lake of <strong>Lough Lein, Killarney's Lower Lake</strong>, The Lake Hotel enjoys the most magnificent setting with the truly unique backdrop of the mountains, islands, woodlands and the 12th century McCarthy M&oacute;r castle ruins.
      The Lake Hotel is a four star property run by the <strong>Huggard Family</strong> & has been welcoming guests since 1820, so a long tradition of warm Irish hospitality awaits all visitors.
      <br>
      <br>Awaken for breakfast in the elegant dining room, The <span style="color:#a5945d; font-weight:bold;">Castlelough Restaurant </span>. Observe the wild deer stroll across the lawn, unwind over morning coffee in the <span style="color:#a5945d; font-weight:bold;">Lakeside Bistro</span> and
      absorb the peace and tranquillity imposed by the presence of the lakes. Wander down the pathways to the ancient castle ruins and be surrounded by the freshest of air and a landscape that is untouched but admired by visitors over the centuries. As
      the light fades and colours change, enjoy an aperitif in the Devil's Punch Bowl Bar before tasting the finest of Irish food and reflecting on the abundance of natural beauty in this part of the world.</p>
  </div>

  <nav id="navbot">
    <ul>
      <li>The Hotel</li>
      <li>Rooms</li>
      <li>Dining</li>
      <li>NewsLetter</li>
      <li style="border-right-width:1px; border-right-style:solid; border-right-color:#D8D8D8;">Gallery</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Only the Index.html file currently contains the form that I was trying to work with, I will add the form to the rest of the pages myself once I hopefully know how to!

Comment: We don't see the external links though you have rar files and would we extract and see to see the problem. Do always post relevant code in your question. And welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal! But it won't let me post my code in the question for some reason, keeps asking me to indent it but when I do that it still won't let me post it. - Pastebin Link - http://pastebin.com/bDTsXk4D

Answer (score 1):

[image]the quickest solution is to add:

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

but I think you should group the topleft, logo and form block inside another div and then update the css

Comment: I wouldn't know how to go about updating the CSS at this stage, I just am way too confused as is but thanks for the suggestion! And your solution also works but when I try and give a padding or a margin to the right-hand side of the form, it moves the logo again, any ideas?

Comment: change the css selector from .text to p.text (line: 122) and then add the padding or margin to the form

Comment: All sorted! Thanks for everyones answers.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the padding-left in both form and trip advisor image : )

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I took away the padding-left from the tripadvisor image but I have no padding-left on the form so I wasn't able to fix the issue! Any other suggestions?

Comment: The form has a class .text with the following css: `.text {
color: #21334b;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 15px;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 150px;
padding-bottom: 1.5em;}`. That padding is what's making the logo move.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is position absolute, if you set #topleft position to relative then logo will find the correct place to stay itself!
so just Change this:

```
#topleft
    {
        position:absolute;
        float:left;
    }
```

to :

```
#topleft
        {
            position:relative;
            float:left;
        }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works but now when I try to give a padding or a margin to move in the form, it moves the logo again, any ideas?